# How do I style a PHP form

Tags: php, html, css

I want to make it so that the table/form boxes that hold the data are longer so you can read all the text that is inside without having to go inside of it.
I tried using CSS but is there a way within the PHP? Here is an image of what it looks like currently with a bit of CSS.

[image]

```
<table>    
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Venue ID</th>
        <th>Category </th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>End Date</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
    {
        echo "<tr><form action=edit.php method=post>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name=title value='".$row['eventTitle'],"'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name=venue value='".$row['venueID'],"'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name=cat value='".$row['catID'],"'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name=start value='".$row['eventStartDate'],"'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name=end Date value='".$row['eventEndDate'],"'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name=price value ='".$row['eventPrice'],"'></td>";
        echo "<input type=hidden name=id value='".$row['eventID']."'>";

        echo "<td><input type=submit value=Edit></td>";
        echo "</form></tr>";
    }

    ?>

</table>
```

Comment: *"I tried using CSS but is there a way within the php?"* - Basically the same method as you'd code it in HTML. This is ***"CSS 101"***.

Comment: `"I tried using CSS"` - And did you encounter any actual problem in that attempt?  Because "using CSS" is exactly how you'd do this.

Comment: you should use some open source framework for styling like Bootstrap, Foundation, HTML KickStart etc.

Comment: @david what would I add into the css to increase the width of the cell?

Comment: maybe `width: 100px;` or however wide you want it?

Comment: HTML side note: `<form>` cannot be made child of `<table>`.

Comment: I need to style the form, not the table.. how would I do that since it's in php?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abrahammurciano/2o9011rz/1/ is this what you mean?

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon yes it is but this is the result. I think because td is in the php http://i.imgur.com/XBviAtY.png

Comment: @Tinny it's definitely not because the code is in the php. As I explained in my answer, the CSS cannot differentiate between HTML and outputs of PHP

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused as to how to style code which is produced by PHP.
But it is actually exactly the same as regular HTML.

PHP is a server side language. So what it does is work out the code on the server, and then send the results to the browser as plain HTML.

HTML and CSS are client side. So the server sends the code over without any processing, and the browser figures out what to do with it.

But to the browser, the code received from the PHP is actually the same as plain HTML.

So to answer your question "but is there a way within the php?", you just have to code the CSS as if you were styling static HTML. There is no way to style within PHP.

You can either put your CSS in a separate file and link to it with a `<link>` tag or you could put it in `<style>` tags in the head of the document and then using `class="mycssclass"`, or you put it as a `style` attribute within the HTML​.

So basically your answer is to use regular CSS and put this into it

```
td{
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:1px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

td input {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Ah ok I understand thanks for the explanation, however I have implemented the CSS and this is the result. http://i.imgur.com/G8CcWz3.png

Comment: ah yes that could be why, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe width:100% for the inputs. Not sure. Will check it out

Comment: I've found a solution. I added class after input and it is letting me change the input in CSS.. thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Yep. That's coz php outputs are styled in exactly the same way as HTML